# How to solve this system of IVP differential equations

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I have a system of differential equations like this

`dy/dt = f(t,y,y1,y2,....,yn,x),
dy1/dt = f(t,y,y1,y2,..yn,x),
.
.
.
dyn/dt = f(t,y,y1,y2,..yn,x),
x(t) = f(t,y1,y2,...yn,x)`

And I have the values y_i(0),x(0)
If I had dx/dt then simply using scipy.integrate IVP I could solve this.  I can't calculate the derivative of x(t) it's too complex . Can I simulate this system in python without finding dx/dt ?

Answer (score 0):

No problem, define

```py
def derivatives(t,y):
    xt = func_x(t,y);
    dy = func_y(t,y,xt)
    return dy
```

where `func_y` takes scalar (`t`,`xt`) and vector (`y`) arguments and returns a vector of the same size as `y`. This then works well with `solve_ivp`.

Comment: But I have expression where x(t) also appears on the rhs  as well . X(t) = f(t,y1,y2,y3,...,x) .

Comment: Also how do I use x(0) value

Comment: Is $x=X(t)$? Then you need a function solver to get the value inside the derivatives function, or you need to treat the whole system as DAE system. // But is `x(0)=f(0,y(0),x(0))`?

Comment: Yes x(t) and X(t) are same . No x(0) has different value